# Text mining software (beyond R)

Tags: software, text-mining

I am looking for software for teaching text mining to business students. Unfortunately, I cannot consider programming languages like R. Does anyone have experience with other text mining software? Can you recommend it? (or not!)

Ideally, software that is easy to learn for non-technical people, not overly expensive (not necessarily free), which can be used to convey the concepts of text mining clearly (rather than getting bogged down in software details).

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen a flyer for a text mining workshop that used something called WordSmith: http://www.lexically.net/wordsmith/

Comment: @Macro: I am looking for software suggestions that are based on personal experience, and ideally experience teaching with it in a non-technical context such a business schools.

Comment: OK. I don't have personal experience with WordSmith but a consulting group (affiliated with a university) I used to work for taught a text mining workshop to non-statisticians that used it. Many of the workshop participants were from the business school.

Comment: SAS also offers a text mining solution which is pretty good and user friendly. http://www.sas.com/en_us/software/analytics/text-miner.html

Answer (score 11):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org) is free and reasonably easy to use, though it does require installing Python.  It comes with a wide range of text data sets.  There's an O'Reilly book for it, which is a help for students.

[WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is general machine learning software with a nice interface.  There's some text classification datasets for it, though not the range of text mining datasets there is for NLTK. There's a book for WEKA too.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for providing links and reasons for your recommendations.  Welcome to our community!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Rapidminer. Good documentation and a good community where people can discuss various questions. Works both on Mac and Windows.

http://rapid-i.com

Comment: You can search for RapidMiner text mining examples at MyExperiment:
http://www.myexperiment.org/workflows

Answer (score -2):

[DMelt](http://jwork.org/dmelt/) is a free software package for computation, visualization and data mining. It is designed to work with large data ("big data") and perform statistical analysis and data mining. It is similar to R, but is integrated with a number of programming languages (such as Python)

Comment: And text mining?